# `autoload` raises an error but `require` does not (ruby)

Tags: ruby, rubygems

In my Ruby program, I'm trying to lazy-load a library ([crack](http://github.com/jnunemaker/crack/tree/master) for the curious).

If I do this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'crack'
```

Everything is working fine. However, when I try this:

```
require 'rubygems'
autoload :Crack, 'crack'
```

A LoadError is raised. (*no such file to load -- crack*)

Why is this error being raised? Is it because 'crack' (and therefore my other user-installed gems) are not in my $LOAD_PATH?

*edit:*

Furthermore, `autoload` does work with the Standard Library:

```
autoload :Yaml, 'yaml'
```

works fine, and raises no errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to add the 'crack' gem to your $LOAD_PATH by doing:

```
gem 'crack'
```

This is necessary because RubyGems replaces Kernel#require with a method that attempts to "activate" the gem before requiring it  if necessary, but doesn't do the same thing for Kernel#load - and autoload calls load on the backend.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for explaining Kernel#require, too! Do I need to place this before or after `require 'rubygems'` or does it matter?

Comment: after: the "gem" method is added to Kernel by rubygems, so it's not going to be available until after rubygems has been required.