# Why is autoload failing to load files for gems

Tags: ruby, email, rubygems, gmail

I am trying to read emails in ruby using this [gmail gem](https://github.com/nu7hatch/gmail).

When I `require 'gmail'` in IRB or in a script, I get this error:

`/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/gmail-0.4.0/lib/gmail.rb:70:in connect_with_proper_client': no such file to load -- gmail/client (LoadError)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/gmail-0.4.0/lib/gmail.rb:48:in new`

This is happening because autoload cannot file the 'gmail/client' file.

When I add `require 'gmail/client'` manually, the problem goes away till the next autoload call. This solution is unacceptable because I cannot anticipate which files to add in advance.

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849622/autoload-raises-an-error-but-require-does-not-ruby), however it didn't remedy my problem.

Comment: If I uninstall the gem, then reinstall it, I can use the gem, but only once.

Comment: I tried to reproduce with ruby 1.8.7 but was unable to make this error happen. Can you create a minimal script that makes this happen for you and post the code.

Comment: Also just to make sure..you haven't installed something like `faster_require` or similar gem accelerator that might interfere with gem loading?

Comment: Something doesn't add up, there is no line 70 of the gmail gem version 0.4.0 https://github.com/nu7hatch/gmail/blob/e9b6ecc232764c080a03982f39b9c97fdd1ba96d/lib/gmail.rb

Comment: @Casper I tried requiring easyload, but that had no affect. 
I built the gem from github, and same issue
`/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/gmail-0.4.0/lib/gmail.rb:50:in 'new': no such file to load -- gmail/client (LoadError)`

I found the issue is a conflict with the 'parse_resource' library. It is beyond the scope of this question to ask about resolving the conflict.

Comment: I ask a question about gem conflicts here: [Ruby autoload conflicts between gmail and parse_resource gems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12237941/ruby-autoload-conflicts-between-gmail-and-parse-resource-gems)