# Ruby autoload conflicts between gmail and parse_resource gems

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rubygems, gmail, parse-platform

[Earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231134/why-is-autoload-failing-to-load-files-for-gems#comment16393317_12231134), I asked about autoload in the gmail gem not being able to find the files it wanted to load. In building a minimal script, I found the gmail gem loaded it's files when I didn't include the parse_resource gem.

The [gmail gem](https://github.com/nu7hatch/gmail) lets you access your emails, labels, and inboxes from gmail.  The [parse_resource gem](https://github.com/adelevie/parse_resource) wraps the [parse.com](http://parse.com/) api in an ActiveRecord pattern.

If I include the parse_resource gem *before* the gmail gem, ruby throws a LoadError.

These are the permutations of the minimal script I wrote, organized by error.

## LoadError

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'parse_resource' 
require 'gmail'

Gmail.new('yourEmail@gmail.com', 'password')
```

## Works Fine

```
require 'rubygems'
#require 'parse_resource'
require 'gmail'

Gmail.new('yourEmail@gmail.com', 'password')
```

## Autoload Error

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'gmail'
require 'parse_resource' 

Gmail.new('yourEmail@gmail.com', 'password')
```

`/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/gmail-0.4.0/lib/gmail.rb:50:in 'new': no such file to load -- gmail/client (LoadError)
    from emailError.rb:6`

How do I include both the parse_resource and gmail gems into my programs?

-Nick

Comment: Are you using bundler, or even just have a `Gemfile`? [`parse_resource` requires `bundler/setup`](https://github.com/adelevie/parse_resource/blob/v1.7.2/lib/parse_resource/base.rb#L2), and this could be causing problems with your load path.

Comment: @matt Yes, I'm specifying gems in a Gemfile, and running `bundle install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had installed the gems with bundler.

To fix the issue with loading both libraries, I installed the gems with the gem command:
`sudo gem install gmail parse_resource`

With this done, I was able to require the libraries in any order, and to connect to gmail and parse without issue.

-Nick