# Gmail gem error when run inside Rspec - 'cannot load such file -- gmail/client'

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubygems

I'm using this gem called [gmail](https://github.com/gmailgem/gmail) and it works perfectly when run in just a plain ruby script. However, when used inside Rspec, I keep getting this error.

```
Failure/Error: @gmailnew = Gmail.new()
LoadError:
cannot load such file -- gmail/client
# /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/gmail-0.6.0/lib/gmail.rb:50:in new' 
# ./temp.rb:7:inblock (2 levels) in '
```

Any idea what causes this? 
- I've already tried reinstalling it since it seems to be not finding a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not figure out what causes the conflict, similar problems by others.

[Why is autoload failing to load files for gems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231134/why-is-autoload-failing-to-load-files-for-gems)

[Ruby autoload conflicts between gmail and parse_resource gems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12237941/ruby-autoload-conflicts-between-gmail-and-parse-resource-gems)

I was able to resolve this by using Bundler. 
1) Added gem inside the Gemfile (gem 'gmail') 
2) $ bundle install - this installs all gems inside the Gemfile, and avoids the conflicts 
3) $ bundle exec rspec my_spec_file.rb - executes Rspec